# Join query in specific column table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table with query i can get final price , i want join query to table as new column.

[image]

my query:

```
SELECT ID , Name FROM dbo.AshkhasList

select dbo.Person_Mande(40,'1398/01/01','1400/12/29',DEFAULT)
```

**line 1** query call table with id and name , **line 2** get final price as `id`.
i want join final price query line 2 as column name Price inside name in result.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Considering that's an image of SSMS, I *assume* you're using SQL Server, not MSSQL.

Comment: Add sample data from different tables with your expected output.

Comment: As for if you want to "join" the query, have you considered using a `JOIN`?

Comment: Sure i want join Price inside id , name column

Comment: So, what's wrong with a `JOIN`?

Comment: @Larnu i don't know how to join into result as column , right `select dbo.Person_Mande(id,'1398/01/01','1400/12/29',DEFAULT)` id my users with line 1 query can get id

Comment: You don't join to a column, you join to a table, view, or table value function. If the above is a (i)TVF, then use `APPLY`. If it's a Scalar Function you can't "join" to it; it just goes in your `SELECT`. You haven't explained anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my problem:

```
SELECT ID , Name , dbo.Person_Mande(ID,'1398/01/01','1400/12/29',DEFAULT) AS Mande FROM dbo.AshkhasList
```